# How to extract tweet and store it in CSV file?

Tags: python, twitter, export-to-csv

I have write this code to save the `id` and `tweet` I extract from specific user but the problem is it save only the first tweet with index 50 I try the counter but nothing happens.

```
a=50
for info in tweets[:a]:
   with open(userID+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
     writer = csv.writer(file)
     writer.writerow(["id", "tweet"])
     writer.writerow([info.id,info.full_text+ "\n"])
     a-=1
```

Comment: You don't need the variable `a` to traverse the list in reverse, you can use the built-in `reversed(tweets)`

Comment: You are getting only 1 row in the file because you are using write mode. The existing text is getting replaced in each iteration.

Comment: Hi Sara. As you can see on other questions on StackOverflow, you don't have to write your question in Uppercase. Instead, write it correctly in the question Title.

Comment: I am thankful to u all yes it work when I change the mode to 'a'

Comment: hi Dorian I will be attention next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use append mode instead of write.

```
with open(userID+'.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
```

'w' : write mode actually replaces the existing content. 'a' : append mode adds data to the existing file.
Read here :
https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html